# how to get element IDs using regular expression in dojo

Tags: javascript, html, regex, dom, dojo

I have many input fields like:

```
<input id="number1" type="text" />
<input id="number2" type="text" />
<input id="number3" type="text" />
<input id="number4" type="text" />
```

I want to get all ids starting with "number" followed with a number.

any function(in dojo library) which helps me get these values..

Comment: How about giving them all the same class and get by class?

Comment: i have already used these ids in different places. so i cant change it.. i want to get them using ids only

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
 console.log(dojo.query("[id^='number']"));
```

this gets all the filed with id starting from number

Comment: Yes that was what I was about to say.  You can then run a forEach on the returned array, testing it against /number\d+/ regX.